# With mimosa is it possible to separate bower assets?

Tags: mimosa

Mimosa provides for the directory structure ...

- assets (the watch.sourceDir)
- assets/JavaScript files (Bower installs to a vendor directory here)
- public

extract from mimosa-config.coffee ...

```
vendor:                              # settings for vendor assets
  javascripts: "javascripts/vendor"  # location, relative to the watch.sourceDir
```

Is it possible to use the following structure? ...

- assets
- bower (will contain vendor assets only)
- public (will contain both assets and bower on a build)

or must the proposed "bower" dir be relative to the watch.sourceDir? Are there any known workarounds? Should I avoid workarounds?

PS: This is a structure my employer wishes to adopt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how I missed this!

Recently a new config has been added to mimosa-bower.  `strategy: together` is what you want.

Here's the docs for `together`: https://github.com/dbashford/mimosa-bower#strategy-together

And here's an example app (using Polymer) that uses that strategy: https://github.com/brzpegasus/mimosa-polymer-demo